# Gitlab CI: Using wildcard with include keyword

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using below to trigger pipeline if any changes are made in the folders under root directory.

```
trigger_serviceA:
  stage: triggers  
  rules:        
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"'
      changes: 
        - serviceA/*      
      when: always  
  trigger:
    include: serviceA/.gitlab-ci.yml    
    strategy: depend
```

However, pipeline is not getting triggered if there are any changes in the subfolders under serviceA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `only:changes` the single wildcard [does not covers subdirs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychanges--exceptchanges) - you'll have to use `/**/*` instead.

Altough the documentation does not say it, i could imagine that it's the same for `rules:changes` - so maybe you'll want to try that out.